# How to use a fixed algorithm in FFTW

Tags: fftw

I read from the manual that FFTW does n't use a fixed algorithm to compute the transforms. 
http://www.fftw.org/fftw3.pdf

But I would like to use the same algorithm in my computations. Does anyone know how to force FFTW to use the same algorithm? Thanks.

By the way I'm writing my programs in Fortran.

Comment: It's the same *algorithm* but FFTW dynamically chooses different optimised butterfly arrangements to get optimal throughput. If you want to use the same *code path* though then I suggest reading the chapter on FFTW "wisdom", then generate wisdom once and re-use it.

Comment: Thanks Paul R. So you say that I have to use 'wisdom' - do an export and import of a plan created initially - if I were to use the same config for my programs. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This does limit you to a specific platform though, but if you're just doing this on one machine then it's no problem.